Password Hashes on AG Nodes
I'm comparing the password hashes of SQL logins on AG nodes. Of the twenty SQL logins 15 have the same hashes over the 2 nodes and 5 have different hashes.
Is a different hash an indicator of a different password, or could a salt have been added to some passwords and not others.
Ideally we wouldn't be using SQL logins at all, but our hand is forced in some instances

how do you see the password hashes ?  using the sp_help_revlogin ?

A different password_hash in sys.sql_logins is a clear indicator of a different password — that is unless there are different versions of SQL in play.

Thanks Andreas, I thought that was the case, but thought I'd check with the community before highlighting the issue to my team
